# What is the Rust equivalent of TypeScript's Array.map with destructuring?

Tags: typescript, rust

In TypeScript, you can map and destructure a partial set of data from an interface, using the following

```js
interface Person {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

function getName({ name }: Person): Partial<Person> {
  return ({ name });
}

const people: Person[] = [
  {
    name: "Sally",
    address: "1234 E Test St."
  },
  // ...
];

const names = people.map(getName);
// => [{ "name": "Sally" }, ...]
```

I've been reading the Rust docs and maybe I'm just not understanding, but I haven't found a 1:1 equivalent on how to do this TypeScript operation in Rust. Is it possible to perform this type of destructure in Rust? Perhaps using `map` or `filter_map`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rust also has destructuring via [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch18-00-patterns.html):

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
    address: String,
}

fn get_name(Person { name, .. }: Person) -> String {
    name
}

fn main() {
    let people = vec![Person {
        name: String::from("Sally"),
        address: String::from("1234 E Test St."),
    }];

    let names: Vec<_> = people.into_iter().map(get_name).collect();
    println!("{:?}", names);
}
```

You won't usually see people do this type of destructuring in function signatures, however. It exposes more of the implementation in the automatically generated documentation. It's more common to see it immediately inside of a function:

```
fn get_name(person: Person) -> String {
    let Person { name, .. } = person;
    name
}
```

And people don't frequently use destructuring in `let` variables unless they are pulling out many values. In this case, it's shorter to just use the field directly:

```
fn get_name(person: Person) -> String {
    person.name
}
```

This particular function isn't *super* useful, so I'd also usually see it as a closure:

```
.map(|p| p.name)
```

There's many things in your original TypeScript that don't translate directly to Rust:

1. The concept of the `Partial` type.
2. Rust vectors themselves do not implement `map` and friends — those operations belong to [iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). These are *lazy*, which allows the Rust to be much more efficient than the corresponding JS.
3. There are multiple string types.

> What if I wanted to destructure more than one property?

If you wanted an anonymous collection of fields, you'd usually use a *tuple*:

```
fn get_name_things(Person { name, .. }: Person) -> (String, usize) {
    (name, 42)
}
```

There's no concept of one-off structs with named fields.

Comment: I was afraid it was that easy. Thank you so much. I guess a follow-up question, since you know what you're doing. What if I wanted to destructure more than one property? I wouldn't just return a `String`, would I?

Comment: @BrittanyMazza You can take as many attributes from the `Person` record as you want, and map them to anything you like.

Comment: @Bergi That's what I'm not understanding, and would be great to be able to visualize this. What would be the return type of the new `get_[props]` function? And what is the shape of the returned value? Let's suppose I wanted both `name` and `address` and had many more fields. Would I Just return `{ name, address }`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I really appreciate your help and your clear answer. I was afraid that Rust didn't have one-off structs, but I may actually be able to return a different struct with only the fields I needed. Obvious, this is probably not the Rust way of doing things.

Comment: @BrittanyMazza note that you don't have to actually extract the values in many cases, you can just get a reference to them. You may also wish to proactively create structures and nest them inside of each other. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=17b42c4d635141a2f76206f82574c889)

Comment: @BrittanyMazza If you want multiple fields, why not just use the original structure?  As "one-off structs" you can use [tuples](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch03-02-data-types.html#the-tuple-type)